# Universal links with AUTH0 iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking, auth0, ios-universal-links

Hello Here i want to perform universal deep linking to my iOS app but due to the path not as per we want we can’t able to perform universal deep linking in my iOS app. I also refer [Path in universal link](https://community.auth0.com/t/path-in-universal-links-configurable/7402) but we are not getting solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old repo, but might be helpful github.com/Satish/iOS-Universal-Links

You need to host `apple-app-site-association` at `http://your-site.com/` domain (ie. `http://your-site.com/apple-app-site-association`).

```
 {
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XXXX.nnnn",
                "paths": [
                    "/yourpath"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

Without this its impossible to open the app with `http://your-site.com/yourpath` link(s)

Actually, with this, they also identify that you own that domain and wants to open `XXXX.nnnn` app with links to the mentioned domain (ie. `http://your-site.com/yourpath`)